# Are there any database engines which will intuit the join condition based on the existing foreign keys?

Tags: database-recommendation, feature-comparison, join, foreign-key

It seems strange to me that, when I've defined a foreign key, the engine cannot use this information to automatically figure out the correct JOIN expressions, but instead requires me to re-type the same clauses. Are there any databases, perhaps some kind of research project, that will inspect the existing foreign keys?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any that use foreign keys (and that would can be messy if you have more than one foreign key back to the same table)

But [Oracle will base joins off of name of columns if you don't specify a specific join type nor a join condition, or if you use `NATURAL JOIN`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-an-effective-way-of-labeling-columns-in-a-database/45#45)

Comment: Why would it be messy if you have more than one foreign key to the same table. If you are looking at it from the "parent" table perspective it should still be clear as to what record in the child you are interested in.

Comment: @Bitoff you might have more than one relationship between the two tables, and so not a composite key, but actually more than one foreign key to the child table.  Eg, in a previous job, we had a database of organizations, and in that table there are two links to my table of people -- head of the department, and the primary contact (usually, the secretary).  There was a foreign key in the opposite direction, as staff members are assigned to a department, until we had to break it out to support many-to-many relationships.

Comment: I know none of the common RDBMSes do this - as the question states, I put the question out there to see if anyone had heard of anything new in this area.

Comment: -1 This is not right about Oracle behaviour, and neither was your answer that you link to. As pointed out by Gary (the third comment to your answer), "`natural join` has never been the default". Incidentally, Tom Kyte is surely right when he calls `natural join` [a bug waiting to happen](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:13430766143199)

Answer (score 4):

It *would* be really cool if I could write this

```
from calendar join table1
```

and the dbms would know that it needs to evaluate this.

```
from calendar
left join table1 on (work_date between (cal_date - 13) and cal_date)
```

*Really* cool.  But not every join is an [equi-join](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Equi_join).

FWIW, `NATURAL JOIN` is in the SQL standard. But I'm pretty sure I haven't used it in the last 25 years.

If you find yourself writing the same join clauses over and over, maybe you just need more views.

Answer (score 3):

There are auto-complete utils for your editor of choice to auto-suggest appropriate join statements if typing is the concern. RedGate's SQL Prompt for handling SQL Server in SSMS & Visual Studio. I believe Quest's TOAD will handle Oracle and some of the other more popular RDMSs.

Comment: No real "concern", just wondering if this is something anyone is looking into addressing.

Comment: @TML I doubt anyone is worried about this as this is really in the domain of application logic to my understanding (where application logic is the things that don't pertain to running a database server, the things we get paid to do)